# Synchronize the contents of two EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I would like to synchronize the contents of two EditTexts. The first is created dynamically in Java and the second is created in XML. I hope for your help.

Comment: I tried to do it this way: edittext1 = edittext2.getText(); and even so:

String newString = edittext1.getText().toString();. 
edittext2 = setText(newString);

Comment: Just added your code snippet in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment above, it looks like you're missing some basic understanding in Java or code in general. Either that or you posted a snippet that's impossible to understand without some more context.

```
I tried to do it this way: edittext1 = edittext2.getText();
```

You cannot assign a String to an EditText...

```
and even so: String newString = edittext1.getText().toString();.
```

That's the right way to get the String..

> edittext2 = setText(newString);

Hard to make any sense of this. Are you assigning the (unspecified) result of setText() to the editText2 variable? This probably makes no sense.

You just need `editText2.setText(editText1.getText().toString());`